# Resetar React-Select (Unform) após submit

Tags: react, typescript

Estou estudando ReactJS e Typescript, e também uma lib para formulários chamada Unform (https://github.com/Rocketseat/unform).

Tenho um formulário com alguns campos, dentre eles um campo Select (https://react-select.com/). Meu problema é: Como limpar esse campo react-select após enviar o formulário?

Repositório do meu projeto:
https://github.com/fredarend/icetec-frontend

O formulário está em: src/pages/Dashboard/indext.tsx e o componente de Select está em src/components/Select/index.tsx.

Percebam que no index de Dashboard já utilizei o `formRef.current?.reset()` após enviar os dados para a API, porém, está resetando somente os inputs, o Select não continua com preenchido.

Não estou conseguindo implementar nada que funcione, alguém talvez já tenha feito isso?

Desde já, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: `value={selectedOption}` nesse parte do código você seta `selectedOption = null` geralmente com variável de estado do componente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi prq tantos negativos..

Postei a mesma dúvida no stackoverflow gringo, me ajudaram e ainda deram +1..

Enfim, consegui resolver utilizando a solução de pegar o ref do campo e limpar somente ele:

```
const select = formRef!.current!.getFieldRef('technologies');
select.select.clearValue()
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63782116/reset-react-select-unform-after-submit/63783359#63783359

Answer (score 0):

Adicione estas linhas no `registerField` do seu componente react-select.

```
clearValue: (ref: any) => {
  ref.select.clearValue();
}
```

Quando o `clear` for chamado, seja por:

`formRef.current.clearField('field-name');` ou 
`formRef.current.reset();` ou

```
function handleSubmit(data, { reset }) {
    reset();
}
```

o `clearValue` será chamado e o `ref.select.clearValue()` limpará o campo.